# Does the use of ButterKnife make app slower?

Tags: android, butterknife

I've started to use ButterKnife in my android app just to see the difference between it and "findViewById", what I found was that the UI is sort of sluggish and there's a small lag when I open an activity or fragment. 
Does ButterKnife create this small lag?

Comment: It adds some lag certainly-  it needs to perform a reflection analysis of your activity, and walk the view hierarchy to find matches.  But how much lag is hard to quantify, it depends on activity and layout complexity.  Have you tried profiling the app and seeing where time is spent?

Comment: I did perform some profiling, the thing is Butterknife is compiled at runtime, even though it's simplifying the code, I don't want that kind of delay in the app. Is there an alternative to Butterknife?

Comment: If you really want to use Dependency Injection google recommends `Dagger2` https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory#remove but there will still probably be some sort of performance hit

Comment: @tyczj They really do something totally different.  Dagger 2 is about dependency injection, Butterknife is about view/resource injection

Comment: THe easiest alternative to Butterknife is just to not use anything.  It saves you about 4 keystrokes per view over just using findViewById in onCreate.

Comment: or use kotlin with [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Let's check what id does behind the scenes. It uses annotation interface, to make the same things, difference only in compile time, when you cache of built files is empty.

Each `Bind` annotation do the same with usual finding View, with id, and saving to the local view id's collections. It's very simple, because nothing special there. Just check custom interface implementation, you can implement simple `Butterknife` by yourself.

Comment: @GabeSechan https://guides.codepath.com/android/reducing-view-boilerplate-with-butterknife

Answer (score 0):

> Butterknife uses compile-time annotations which means there is no additional cost at run-time. Instead of slow reflection, code is generated ahead of time. Calling bind delegates to this generated code that you can see and debug. This means that Butterknife does not slow down your app at all! ([Source](https://guides.codepath.com/android/reducing-view-boilerplate-with-butterknife))

This should clarify your concern. There has to be another issue leading to your lag. Maybe analyze it with the [CPU Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler) to find the reason for it.